# Using AWK, how to use tabs instead of Space as field seperator?

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk

I have the following fields:

```
Name<tab>City<tab>Phone Number
```

If I use to `awk`, it returns only first name ("Muhammad"), when name is "Muhammad Tahir".

How can I use `awk` with `grep` so it uses tabs as a field separators instead of spaces?

Comment: Does this resource from Stack Overflow help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374239/tab-separated-values-in-awk ? I vote to close as this is not Ubuntu specific bt should be asked in a different forum.

Comment: @Graham [Are “not only Ubuntu-specific” questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14523/are-not-only-ubuntu-specific-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

Use `-F` option:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{...}'
```

or set the field separator (`FS`) in the `BEGIN` section:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{...}'
```

---

To also set the Output field separator, use `OFS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=FS}{...}'
```